# How to use 1 regex in python to scrape info on 2 different lines?

Tags: python, regex

Ex: some_name and some_price are on 2 different lines

```
<name="some_name" >
<price="some_price" >
```

How can I use 1 regex in python to scrape info on 2 different lines?

Comment: explain a bit more with some example and expected output.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: If this is a markup language, you should be using a parser and not regex.

Comment: if it's a large file then it's better to use parsers like Beautifulsoup(html), lxml(xml),etc.

Comment: I'd like to scrape all product names and their prices on a webpage, but they are on different lines, can I use something like this: match=re.compile(<name="(.+?)>\n <price="(.+?)">).findall(link)

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses a single regular expression to match values on two separate lines.

In general, this isn't done; a single expression is matched per line, for example in a loop.

### source

```
import re

mystring = '''<name="some_name" >
<price="some_price" >
'''

pat = re.compile('\w+=.(\w+).+\w+=.(\w+)', re.DOTALL)
res = pat.search(mystring)
print res and res.groups()
```

### output

```
('some_name', 'some_price')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  x='<name="some_name" >\n<price="some_price" '
  print re.findall(r".*?=\"(.*?)\"",x)
```

This works for as many pairs you want for as many lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookbehinds with logical OR operator to print the values of `name`, `price` tags.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''<name="some_name" >
... <price="some_price" >'''
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=<name=")[^"]*|(?<=<price=")[^"]*', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
some_name
some_price
```